# How to sort an array of odd numbers in ascending order, but keep even numbers at their position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, modulus

I want to sort only odd numbers without moving even numbers. For example, when I write :

```
sortArray([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4])
```

The expected result is :

```
[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

I am new to JavaScript and I came across a challenge on the Internet that has me perplexed. I normally wouldn't post asking for a solution on the Internet, BUT I have tried for hours and I would like to learn this concept in JavaScript.

The challenge states :

*You have an array of numbers.
Your task is to sort ascending odd numbers but even numbers must be on their places.
Zero isn't an odd number and you don't need to move it. If you have an empty array, you need to return it.*

Here is my code so far,  please take it easy on me I am in the beginning stages of programming.

```js
function sortArray(array) {
  let oddNums = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      oddNums.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  oddNums = oddNums.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
  array.concat(oddNums);
  array = array.sort((a,b) => a-b);
  return array;
}
```

Comment: @ Nina Scholz the array is at the top of the question

Comment: The challenge and a solution are posted [here](https://gist.github.com/ryunp/9119529bfd2f714bf87306b55e7afbe8) if you're simply looking for a solution to try to reverse engineer to understand.

Comment: I'm thinking create an array of indexes to the odd numbers, then sort the array via the array of indexes to the odd numbers.

Comment: Beware : https://jsperf.com/1447675-vs-1636522-sort-odds-only/. I win, eventhough selection sort is O(n*n) :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could take a helper array for the odd indices and another for the odd numbers, sort them and apply them back on the previously stored indices of the original array.

```js
var array = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4],
    indices = [];

array
    .filter((v, i) => v % 2 && indices.push(i))
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .forEach((v, i) => array[indices[i]] = v);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: first of all, it was not intended to be a functional approach, even if it looks like, but the last line mutates an array, second, every solution need to iterate to identify odd values, then you need to sort these values, then you need to puth the sorted values back to ther old places, by either iterating the odd set, or like in the other good answer of *CRice* iterating the whole array and map even and shift sorted odd values in a new array. by assuming a mutation, that is the signature of the op's given function, i do so.

Comment: Who said you should not iterate ? To be perfectly clear, the first problem is the cost in time of your solution when n is big, https://jsperf.com/1447675-vs-1636522-sort-odds-only/, and the second problem in my point of view is that you are misleading beginners with flashy oneliners to gain more reputation. Think of how many people are proud to produce time expensive code thanks to you :-(

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution using mostly the built-in array methods. Get a list of just the odds, sort it, then map through the original, replacing each item with the first sorted odd if the item is odd, or itself if even:

```js
const array = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4] // to: [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]

function sortOddsOnly(arr) {
    const odds = arr
        .filter(x => x%2)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);
        
    return arr
        .map(x => x%2 ? odds.shift() : x);
}

console.log(sortOddsOnly(array));
```

Comment: This solution works, but for negative numbers you need to surround `x % 2` with `Math.abs` because `-3 % 2` is `-1`.

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution like this.
Build a sorted odd number array 1st, and then fill the rest of even numbers in order:

```js
const arr = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4];

const odd = arr.filter(i => i%2 !== 0).sort();
let i = 0,
  result = [];
arr.forEach(e => {
  if (e%2 === 0) {
    result.push(e)
  } else {
    result.push(odd[i]);
    i++;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a%2 && b%2 ? a - b : 0)
```

If that works depends on the sort algorithm your browser uses.
A browserindependent version:

```
for(const [i1, v1] of arr.entries())
  for(const [i2, v2] of arr.entries())
    if( v1%2 && v2%2 && (i1 < i2) === (v1 > v2))
        ([arr[i1], arr[i2]] = [v2, v1]);
```

Comment: I don't think this will preserve the position of the even numbers.

Comment: @titus it actualky should ... but well it does not :/

Comment: it doesn't output 'true' for the array in the question

Comment: yes,  the sorting stops to early. just run that a few times and see the magic.

Comment: it outputs  [
  3,
  5,
  2,
  8,
  1,
  4
]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using a slightly customized [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) :

```js
var xs = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4];

console.log(sortOddsOnly(xs));

function sortOddsOnly (xs) {
  var n = xs.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (xs[i] % 2 === 1) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (xs[j] % 2 === 1) {
          if (xs[i] > xs[j]) {
            var min = xs[j];
            xs[j] = xs[i];
            xs[i] = min;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return xs;
}
```

The first two `if` guarantee that we swap only odd numbers (`x % 2 === 1` means "x is odd").

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is this. What I have done is created new array `odd`(array with odd position in original array using **[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**) and then sort that array using **[`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**. Then using **[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** change value of all odd element of original array with `odd` array.

```js
x1=[5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4];
function sortArray(array) {
  var odd = array.filter((x,i) => (i+1) % 2 ).sort((a,b) => a > b); //sort odd position and store that in new array
  return array.map((x,i) => (i+1) % 2 ? odd.shift() : x ); //if i is odd then replace it with element from 
                                                  //odd array otherwise keep the element as it is
}
console.log(sortArray(x1));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def sort_array(source_array):
b = sorted([n for n in source_array if  n % 2 != 0])
c = -1
d = []
for i in source_array:
    c = c+1
    if i % 2 != 0 :
        d.append(c)
for x in range (len(d)):
    z = d[x]
    source_array[z] = b[x]
return source_array
```

Comment: This looks like Python, when the solution was required in JavaScript.